# Pass data to Symfony form collection without entity

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am attempting to try and get a collection of "replacements" to work properly but cannot seem to get data passed into the form. There is no entities related in the process just data that I pass in from an external process. Upon submission I will have to validate and apply changes in the system.

snip of my controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/reassignment", name="digitalMarket_category_reassignment")
     * @param ArrayCollection $deletedSubcategories Subcategories being deleted from other request
     * @param Request $request
     * @param NotificationGenerator $ng
     * @return Response
     */
    public function subcategoryReassignment( $deletedSubcategories, Request $request, NotificationGenerator $ng)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(SubcategoryReplacementType::class, ['replacements'=>[
            ['name'=>'offer','handle'=>'handle']
        ]]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){

            dd($form->getData());

        }

        return $this->render('marketplace/category/replacement.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

SubcategoryReplacementType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\DigitalMarket;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class SubcategoryReplacementType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('replacements',CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type' => SubcategoryDeleteType::class,
                'mapped' => false,

            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
//        $resolver->setDefaults();
    }
}
```

SubcategoryDeleteType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\DigitalMarket;


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SubcategoryDeleteType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',TextType::class,[
                'label' => 'Name',
                'required'=>true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('handle',TextType::class,[
                'label' =>'Handle',
                'required'=>true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('oldSub',TextType::class,[
                'label' =>'Old Subcategory',
                'required'=>true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('newSub',EntityType::class,[
                'class'=>Subcategory::class,
                'label'=>'New Subcategory',
                'group_by'=>'category',
                'multiple'=>false,
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'js-select2'
                ],
                'help'=>'Subcategories that will replace one being removed.',
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you don't use an entity, you can still use an object, that won't be related to your database. It's kinda common to put it in a folder "Model" in the src folder or Form. You'd have a cleaner structure, and would be able to use the assertions in annotations. I'm not sure it will fix your issue, but it might, and would make what's happening more clear. Showing your view code could be useful too.

Comment: @FTW thats a thought, and I am a big dummy used "mapped" which doesn't mean to the database but the form. "If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the object, you can set the mapped option to false."

Answer (score 0):

So what I was doing wrong in the case was using "mapped" on the form.

> mapped type: boolean default: true
>
> If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the
> object, you can set the mapped option to false.

You can just pass an array of values:

```
 $form = $this->createForm(SubcategoryReplacementType::class, ['replacements'=>$replacements]);
```